# meteor collections simpleschema, allowedvalues for array?

Tags: node.js, meteor, simple-schema

When i have created a schema:

```
  permissions: {
    type:[String],
    allowedValues: [
      'admin', 'normal',
    ],
  },
```

do the allowedValues checks apply for the elements inside the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this feature request](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/688) you would use this:

```
permissions: {
    type:[String]
},
permissions.$: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: [
        'admin', 'normal'
    ],
}
```

You will need to have a way to ensure that duplicate values don't get pushed onto the array.